# DHCP in Windows Server 2008R2 don't show leases, from a 2003 i can see them

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp

I inherited a network where the Domain controllers where recently upgraded from 2003 to 2008R2.  After the upgrade the DHCP MMC don't show the leases in several of the scopes, only showing a message of "There are no items to show in this view."  All the scopes with the problem have reservations in them.  Otherwise they are practically identical.  If i use the MMC from a 2003 server i can see the leases and work with them without problem.  From a Windows 7 machine i have the same problem.

How can i solve this problem? I could not find a solution in google, only some mentions of it and several "i also have this problem" but no solutions.  Is it caused by the reservations?  Should I record, erase and recreate them?  Or this would not fix this?  Has 2008R2 problems with reservations in DHCP?  or the cause is totally diferent.

Aditional Information from the comments:
The server is the Enterprise Edition of Windows Server 2008R2, and does not have the Hyper-V role.  There aren't superscopes in this server, we have several VLans with DHCP Helper in the Core Switch.  I don't know how the migrations was done, I fear that the migration procedure linked by Ricardo Polo wasn't followed, just any kind of automatic migration there is.

Comment: Two Questions: ¿Is this server a SBS? ¿Does this server have the Hyper-V Role enable?

Comment: Not, it is not a SBS, it is the enterprise edition.  The server with the DHCP does not have the hiper-V role, the other DC has it enabled but not the server with DHCP server.

Comment: Do did you move the DHCP from 2003 to 2008 R2?
Did you follow this procedure? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/962355 Did you do all the steps ?

Comment: I don't know, i just received administration of this server and was informed of the problem.  As there was a "solution" they had not looked for a real solution.  I believe that they just used whatever automatic procedures there are.

Comment: Do you have super scopes?

Comment: No, I have several vlans each with its own scope, and DHCP helper setup in the core.

Comment: Can you view the scopes through netsh?

Comment: Have you looked at the clients that you believe are being allocated IP addresses in these scopes? What does `ipconfig /all` report the DHCP server as being?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing *all* the reserves in the affected scopes the dhcp tools in the 2008R2 server and the Windows 7 Pc could see the leases correctly.  Apparently the reserve information was not migrated correctly.  Several other possible solutions didn't work.

The clients were working correctly all the time this was happening, only the administration from the same server or from a W7 pc could not see the leases.