# w2008R2 DHCP serving leases, but not showing in DHCP console

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp

We upgraded our AD and DHCP to 2008 R2.  I used netsh to dump the dhcp database from the old Windows 2003 R2 server and then imported in the new server.  What I am finding is that not all of the leases it is handing out are ahowing in the DHCP console.  I have tried to reconcile the scope and it doesn't show any errors.

I saw a resolution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/321673/dhcp-in-windows-server-2008r2-dont-show-leases-from-a-2003-i-can-see-them) that seemed similar, but since I have 150 reservations and I am 24 hours shop, re-creating all these doesn't seem like a great idea.

I'm running out of ideas, so any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Is the old server still running? Did you deauthorize it? Did you authorize the new server? Are you checking the console on the server or are you using the DHCP console on a remote computer? If you're looking from a remote computer, are you using RSAT for 2008 R2?

Comment: Old server is long gone and new server is authorized according to AD.  Checking from my workstation with RSAT for 2008 R2.  Same result on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Perform these steps from new W2K8 DHCP server:

1.Open DHCP mmc

2.Open Command prompt: cmd

3.Type: netsh dhcp server export C:\dhcp.txt all in command prompt and press Enter

4.Delete ALL scope information from within the DHCP mmc

5.Type: netsh dhcp server import C:\dhcp.txt all in command prompt and press Enter

6.Right-click server name within DHCP mmc and choose refresh

At this point I was able to view all of my Address Leases.  All entries had a Name that was equal to its Client IP Address, a Lease Expiration of the time of my export, a Type of DHCP/BOOTP, and a very long Unique ID (32 characters).  After performing a "Ipconfig /renew" from a workstation, the workstation's Name appeared correctly, the Type changed to just DHCP, and the Unique ID was the MAC address of the workstation.

I then created a command file (renew.cmd) with the command Ipconfig/renew as the only contents.  I placed this file on a UNC path (\fileserver\sharename\renew.cmd) that I knew all domain users had access to and then sent them an email with the link to the file and instructions to select "Open" after clicking the link.  The proper DHCP registrations just started rolling in after that.

Copied from: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverNIS/thread/1b8cd762-3f95-4ff9-9d9e-75b04e067d2a